# Opencart multi admin for multi store

Tags: admin, opencart

I have setup multi store for my opencart website. I want have 1 user for one store. Example: store1.mystore.com is for user store1. store2.mystore.com is for user store2.

I would like to know how to do this and i really appreciate if there is a module for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

By user I guess You mean the *backend user* == *administrator*? Correct?

Anyway, this is not possible in OpenCart. **If You need this, then You do not need multistore** - just install two different OpenCart instances where You can have two different administrator accounts.

Answer (score 0):

url:- https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=25454

username/password - Pro version - Reset - every hour
demo/demo - Group Separate Products - Admin Users
ex_user2/demo - Group Separate Products - External Users
int_user1/demo - Group Separate Products - Internal Users

Opencart 2.1.0.2
http://bg112.com/oc/demosp/admin

Manages the rights of user and orders.
Allows management of the rights of foreign traders to manage products and orders.
Allows management of the rights of employees to manage products and orders.
Quickly assign products to specific user.
Filter products in person.
Filter products by date added or date of modification. This filter allows the administrator to control the changes of users.
Quick change of the status of many products. Turn on or off products of a specific user.
Quickly assign products to specific users at Dropshipping.
A completely new approach to display and manage orders.
Filter orders in user.
Commission.
Statistics for orders at the store